# what is the best way to analyze user raw query and detect what who want to search

Tags: c#, search-engine, generic-list

i am developing a very basic prototype of web search engine and now i want to know what is the best way to analyze user raw query and detect what who want to search. like Google, Bing, Yahoo etc...

an example user raw query is something like this:

```
Google+Maps+"South+Africa"+Brazil+OR+Italy+OR+Spain+-Argentina+Netherlands
```

and i want to split this to a generic list of each term(single) like this:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TermType, string>>
<TermType.All, "Google">
<TermType.All, "Maps">
<TermType.Exact, "South">
<TermType.Exact, "Africa">
<TermType.Any, "Brazil">
<TermType.Any, "Italy">
<TermType.Any, "Spain">
<TermType.None, "Argentina">
<TermType.None, "Netherland">
```

i don't want complete code, i want guidance, solution, tips or anything that's help me to write best for analyze user raw query.

thanks in advance

Comment: hm..., can you give me correct one?

Comment: The correct parsing of your example is:
((Google AND MAPS AND "Soutch Africa" AND BRAZIL AND Netherlands) AND (Italy OR Spain)) NOT (Argentina)      The AND before the OR part, could be read as a POSSBILY, and not a literal AND for Google's parsing.

Comment: hm..., OK but Argentina and Netherlands together is NOT; however i think my example is lighter from you ;) but thanks. you mean of possibly for AND is "...therlands) **AND** (Italy OR Sp..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think in terms of the query string. Think first in terms of the logical search operations you wish to permit, and how your engine will satisfy them.

How each set of logical operations can be translated from one or more query strings then becomes an implementation detail.

Comment: it's translated like popular search engines. each of terms from left(or based on language can be from right side) starts and filters search results for each term(by TermType which detected for each).